# How to get an element of an object from an array containing the object

Tags: php, arrays, object, element

Here is an array which is response from Stripe payment gateway:

```
$response = Array ( [deleteCardAccount] => Stripe\Card Object ( [_opts:protected] => Stripe\Util\RequestOptions Object ( [headers] => Array ( ) [apiKey] => sk_test_erwppHN9ibdfgdfg0CesaOwnDy ) [_values:protected] => Array ( [id] => card_18SwerIsEZ1YjoOMVAFRLA [currency] => usd [deleted] => 1 ) [_unsavedValues:protected] => Stripe\Util\Set Object ( [_elts:Stripe\Util\Set:private] => Array ( ) ) ...
```

The above array contains the object "Stripe\Card Object" and I want to get value of the element [_values:protected] which is an array.

When I cast the object to an array

```
$nasty_array = (array)$response['deleteCardAccount'];
print_r($nasty_array);
```

I get this array that has keys that start with asterisk:

```
Array ( [*_opts] => Stripe\Util\RequestOptions Object ( [headers] => Array ( ) [apiKey] => sk_test_wejYbwerCerwesaOefg ) [*_values] => Array ( [id] => card_18SwerIsEZ1YjoOMVAFRLA [currency] => usd [deleted] => 1 ) [*_unsavedValues] => Stripe\Util\Set Object ( [_elts:Stripe\Util\Set:private] => Array ( ) ) ...
```

However when I try

```
print_r($nasty_array[*_opts]);
print_r($nasty_array[*_values]);
```

I get

```
error: Undefined index *_values 
error: Undefined index *_opts
```

Questions:

1. Why keys in this array start with asterisk
2. How to access such keys without parsing
3. Is there another way to get an element of an object which is inside of an associative array.

Note: when I manually create an array that has keys that start with asterisk then I can access such keys without a problem, But for some reason I can't access similar keys when casting opject to an array;

Comment: Shouldn't you put quotes around the keys of the array when you access it? `print_r($nasty_array['*_opts']);`

Comment: Without quotes the script doesn't work and produces blank page.

Comment: The reason you can't access those properties is not because the object is inside an array. The reason you can't access them is that they are [protected](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php), which is also the reason they are asterisked/unavailable when you cast the object to array.

Comment: Is this coming as JSON?  If so then decode into an array maybe...

Comment: What specific data do you need from _values? Does the Stripe API not have a method to get the data element you need?

Comment: I need everything from _values. But your suggestion about checking if there is a method is very good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object from the array can be captured into a variable without casting;

```
$captured_object = $response['deleteCardAccount'];
```

And then the elements of the captured object can be simply referenced using "arrow" notation:

```
print_r($captured_object->id);    
print_r($captured_object->currency);
print_r($captured_object->deleted);
```

OR even simpler the object can be referenced directly by mixing the array notation and arrow notation:

```
print $response['deleteCardAccount']->id;
print $response['deleteCardAccount']->currency
print $response['deleteCardAccount']->deleted;
```

This approach works with Stripe response objects but haven't been tested with other objects that have protected properties.